# How to pass reference to opened popup from content script to chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my web app I need to open a popup window via `let popup = window.open(url, 'MyPopupName' ..)` and then somehow get the reference to that window/tab in a chrome extension.

I cannot use any scripts in the popup because url is from another origin. And it seems like there is no easy way to query all tabs in chrome extension via assigned 'MyPopupName' name (except by injecting a script into all tabs and getting window.name via message passing).

Is there an easy way to pass `popup` to the extension and get tabId of the popup window?

Answer (score 0):

Since extensions are subject to the same cross-origin JS restrictions, use [chrome.windows.create](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#method-create) instead of window.open.

```js
async function openPopup(url) {
  const wnd = await chrome.windows.create({
    url, type: 'popup', width: 500, height: 500,
  });
  const tabId = wnd.tabs[0].id;
  console.log(tabId, wnd);
}
```

It is available only in extension pages/frames e.g. `action` popup, options, background script. It means it can't be used in a content script, but you can [send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) with the URL and let the background script open it in its onMessage.

Note that `wnd` is not related to a JavaScript `window` object, it's an entirely [different thing](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#type-Window), so you can't access the new window's globals.

Comment: Opening a popup from extension is an option, however, I need to open it from the content script. And then get the reference to the opened window in the background script of the extension.

Comment: Another idea is to use ```chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true })``` in the background script to get the current window. But since messaging is async, it is not guaranteed that current active window is the one from ```window.open```

Comment: Yes, as the answer says, you can send a message from the content script and use this code in onMessage.

Comment: I don't want to open window from extension, so your answer does not work

Comment: Why? It's the same as window.open + tabs.query essentially but more reliable. There's no way to obtain a direct reference to the window object anyway.

Comment: when opening via content script one may configure options like  status bar , scrollbars, resizable - these options are unavailable with chrome.windows.create. You may only choose for popup or normal window. Also positioning of the popup is much easier within content script as you may directly use values like window.screen.availWidth. These are unavailable in manifest v3, because there is no window object in the background script

Comment: FWIW, many of them have replacements: location:false as type:'popup', scrollbars as chrome.scripting.insertCSS, window.screen as chrome.system.display.getInfo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247083/discussion-between-user2531657-and-woxxom).